# Android 5.1.1 Out of memory Fatal signal 11 error on swiping Viewpager Fragmet

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, segmentation-fault

In my android application I've developed a **Viewpager Fragment**  and inside it, a **Single Fragment** both extend **Fragment** class. The application is working fine but after swiping 10-15 pages forward or backward, it randomly crashes with the following error in logcat:

```
12-20 22:50:21.367: W/ResourceType(21279): Failure getting entry for 0x01080af7 (t=7 e=2807) (error -75)
12-20 22:50:21.747: D/skia(21279): Skia Error: Out Of Memory: (size = 13833300)
12-20 22:50:21.747: A/libc(21279): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 21279 (s.iyykanastaeen)
```

The crash occurs only on **samsung tablet 5.1.1** not on mobile phones.
**EDIT** The crash happens only when custom font is applied using typeface.

```
try{
        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(tvDuaArabic.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/arabtype.ttf");  
         ufont = Typeface.createFromAsset(tvDuaUrdu.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/jameelnoorinastaleeq.ttf");  

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace(); 

            // Prints what exception has been thrown 
            System.out.println(e);
    }

    tvDuaArabic.setTypeface(font);
```

Please help me fix this problem on tablet as well.

Here's the code from Viewpager fragment:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = inflater.getContext();
    rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_single_dua_view_pager, container, false);
    ga= new GridViewAdapter(context);
            return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ll_back_single_dua_header = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ll_back_single_dua_header);
        ll_back_single_dua_footer = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ll_back_single_dua_footer);
        tv_back_single_dua_header_title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_back_single_dua_header_title);

         ufont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/jameelnoorinastaleeq.ttf"); 

        tv_back_single_dua_footer_counter = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_back_single_dua_footer_counter);

        togbtnIsFavorite = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tog_btn_favorite_dua);
        togbtnRepeat = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tog_btn_repeat_dua);
        btnPlayPauseDua = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play_pause_dua);
        btnShareDua = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share_dua);
        btn_list_duas = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_list_duas);

        tv_back_single_dua_footer_counter.setText("1/1");



        mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mPageNumber = position;
            stopMusicPlayback();
            updateView();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
    });
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        String verses = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, "a1");
        String[] versesList = verses.split(",");
        int total = versesList.length;
        int position = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keySelVerseFromList, 0);
        mPager.setCurrentItem((total - 1) - position);
        updateView();

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        repeatDua = false;
        togbtnRepeat.setChecked(false);

        updateView();
        if (new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyPlayAll, false))
            btnPlayPauseDua.performClick();
        super.onResume();       

    }


    void updateView() {


        mPageNumber = mPager.getCurrentItem();
        String verses = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, "a1");
        String[] versesList = verses.split(",");
        int index = (versesList.length - 1) - mPageNumber;
        identifier = versesList[index];


        int resID = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(identifier, "raw", getActivity().getPackageName());
        try {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, resID);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            mp = null;
        }
        btnPlayPauseDua.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_btn_custom);


        tv_back_single_dua_footer_counter.setText((index + 1) + " / " + versesList.length);

    if (new FavoriteDuas().isDuaFavorite(identifier))
            togbtnIsFavorite.setChecked(true);
        else
            togbtnIsFavorite.setChecked(false);

        boolean lang=  new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keylang, false);


        currPos = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        new SharedPreferencesSupplication().save(SingletonClass.keyPlayAll, false);
    stopMusicPlayback();
        super.onPause();
    }

    void stopMusicPlayback() {
        if (mp instanceof MediaPlayer) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
        btnPlayPauseDua.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_btn_custom);

    }

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return (SingleDuaFragment.create(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String verses = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, "a1");
            String[] versesList = verses.split(",");
            return versesList.length;
        }

    }
```

And here's code from SingleFragment:

```
public static SingleDuaFragment create(int pageNumber) {
    SingleDuaFragment fragment = new SingleDuaFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public SingleDuaFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
context = inflater.getContext();
rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_single_dua, container, false);

tvDuaArabic = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_arabic);
tvDuaEnglish = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_english);
tvDuaUrdu = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_urdu);
tvDuaTranslit = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_transl);
tvDuaRef = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ref);

dividerEng = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.divider_english);
dividerUrdu = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.divider_urdu);
dividerTransl = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.divider_transl);
dividerRef = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.divider_ref);
        return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean engTransVisible = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyEngTrans, true);
    boolean urdTransVisible = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyUrdTrans, true);

    String verses = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, "a1");
    String[] versesList = verses.split(",");
    int index = (versesList.length - 1) - mPageNumber;
    String identifier = versesList[index];


    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(tvDuaArabic.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/arabtype.ttf"); 


    //Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(tvDuaArabic.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Tahoma.ttf");
    tvDuaArabic.setText(SingletonClass.duasAra.get(index));
    //tvDuaArabic.setTypeface(custom_font);
    tvDuaArabic.setTypeface(font); 

    tvDuaEnglish.setText(SingletonClass.duasEng.get(index));

    Typeface ufont = Typeface.createFromAsset(tvDuaUrdu.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/jameelnoorinastaleeq.ttf"); 

    tvDuaUrdu.setText(SingletonClass.duasUrd.get(index));
    tvDuaUrdu.setTypeface(ufont);
    tvDuaTranslit.setText(SingletonClass.duasTransl.get(index));








    if(engTransVisible)
    tvDuaRef.setText(SingletonClass.duasRefEng.get(index));
    else if (urdTransVisible)
    tvDuaRef.setText(SingletonClass.duasRefUrd.get(index));
    tvDuaRef.setTypeface(ufont);



    }

    int fontsize = FontSize.getFontSize();
    //Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/PDMS_Saleem_QuranFont-signed.ttf");
    tvDuaArabic.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontsize*2 );
    //tvDuaArabic.setTypeface(font);
    tvDuaEnglish.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontsize);
    tvDuaUrdu.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontsize);
    tvDuaRef.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) (fontsize * 0.75));
    tvDuaTranslit.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) (fontsize * 0.75));
    dividerEng.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) (fontsize * 2));
    dividerUrdu.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) (fontsize * 2));
    dividerRef.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) (fontsize * 2));
    dividerTransl.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) (fontsize * 2));

    boolean engTrans = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyEngTrans, true);
    boolean urduTrans = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyUrdTrans, false);
    boolean refVisible = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyRef, false);
    boolean transVisible = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyTransl, false);

    if (engTrans) {
        tvDuaEnglish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dividerEng.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        tvDuaEnglish.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        dividerEng.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (urduTrans) {
        tvDuaUrdu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dividerUrdu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        tvDuaUrdu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        dividerUrdu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (refVisible) {
        tvDuaRef.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dividerRef.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        tvDuaRef.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        dividerRef.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }   

    if (transVisible) {
    tvDuaTranslit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dividerTransl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    tvDuaTranslit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    dividerTransl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

    if(!engTrans && !urduTrans){
        if(SingletonClass.duasAra.get(index)==""){
            tvDuaEnglish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dividerEng.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //tvDuaEnglish.setText(SingletonClass.duasEng.get(index));
        }


    }

    if(!engTrans && !urduTrans && !transVisible && refVisible){
        tvDuaRef.setText(SingletonClass.duasRefEng.get(index));
    }

    svContent = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sv_content);
    svContent.scrollTo(0, 0);


            super.onResume();
}


public int getPageNumber() {
    return mPageNumber;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You ran out of memory.  Use less.  Look for memory leaks and images that are way too big (you just tried to allocate 13MB, so that's fairly likely).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but does your adapter extend FragmentPagerAdapter? If so, try extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead. I also recommend LeakCanary and the Android Studio memory profiler to check if your fragments are leaking, or something in your fragments

Comment: No resource is present for 0x01080af7 in R.java, does it indicate any problem?

Comment: that indicates that something is missing, like a color, string or image

Comment: Can you please guide how can i figure out that resource? As R.java does not have any entry for the specified address. Thank you

Comment: there is no guide to figuring that out. I recommend checking if all resources that are referenced in your layouts are available.